# Push Notification of Stack Overflow iOS App suddenly flooded my phone

Tags: bug, ios-app

I have not been receiving push notification from Stack Exchange iOS App yesterday until around 12 hours ago. All of the accumulated push notification was flooded to my phone in 1 minute (there were about 20+ push notifications).

FYI, I normally receive 2 to 3 push notifications every hour, mostly come from Stack Overflow.

Is it a potential bug of the iOS App?

Using iOS 8.1.3, Stack Exchange iOS App 1.2.2, iPhone 5s

p.s. my phone has stable Internet connection always, and always switched on. *just feel uncomfortable of not receiving any push notification from Stack community. Am I sick / too addicted?*

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the source of the notifications? Comments/@ tags?

Comment: mainly Comments & Answers by other users.

Comment: Also Android, although not all in one minute. Not sure if it's related, but for me this happened in the ±60 minutes after the network problems for which SE was in read only mode yesterday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was caused by our push notification server not handling outages very well. We'll be working on upgrading it to add in some flood-detection in situations where the queue gets stacked but nothing's going out, since this is definitely quite annoying (I got lots of notifications at once too).

Comment: "...not handling outages very well" ...Crap *goes to restart http://elections.stackexchange.com/*